# Completly remove MySql

Tags: windows, mysql, windows-7, uninstall

How can I completly remove MySql on Windows7 because when I uninstal and I install agan there asking the old password, so the uninstall is not complet, there are remaining some data.

Comment: What did you use to install mySQL? Which version?

Comment: Mysql 5.1 version

Comment: Stupid question I know but are you running the uninstaller as Administrator?

Comment: There are various ways of installing mySQL on a Windows computer. Please at least point out *which one* you used. This is not fit for migration yet

Comment: MySQL Community Server 5.1.57 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove MySQL (preferences etc), you need to uninstall it and **then** remove the corresponding directories.

As you're using 64-Bit Win 7, the directories you should delete are (most likely):

1. C:\Program Files\MySQL *\
2. C:\ProgramData\MySQL *\ (`ProgramData` is a hidden folder)
3. C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\MySQL *\ (`AppData` is also a hidden folder)

When you've done that, you'll be able to reinstall using a completely new password.

All that said, you don't need to do this. You can instead [reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows).